# How to receive the lastest message stored in subscriber queue?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to retrieve the most latest message stored in subscriber queue?? If possible the how??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72121/how-to-receive-the-lastest-message-stored-in-subscriber-queue??/) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2013-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're only interested in the latest messages and want to drop the rest, just set a queue_size of 1, when you create the subscriber.

Otherwise, you'll have to write your own data structure (queue, stack, std::vector) and continually spin to fill your data structure from the callbacks and process it in your own thread.  Be careful of thread safety.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-08-14**:
Thanks a lot..